# Is plugging a wrist strap in enough to prevent ESD?

Tags: esd

I've been told by a few people that if you plug in a PC and switch off its power supply that it is enough to prevent ESD.

But I was taught differently. I was taught that it's more about difference in potential rather than grounding. The way I was taught was that everything must be unplugged, placed on a matt with a grounding strap for the matt and the installer.

If a person follows method 1 will it still cause ESD damage?

Comment: You are correct. "Plugging in the PC prevents ESD damage" assumes the person working on the computer is likely to touch the conductive chassis from time to time, thus reducing the risk of ESD damage. But unlike the ESD-safe environment you suggested, it does not guarantee that no damage will occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've been told by a few people that if you plug in a PC and switch off
>   its power supply that it is enough to prevent ESD.

No, it's not enough to switch off the supply. For most PC's the working voltage has a maximum of 12V, using the Human Body Model (HBM) for Electro Static Discharges (ESD) ranges from 2kV to 8kV, which is hundreds of times more voltage. Whether a circuit is powered on or off will in most cases have very little effect on where the current from an ESD event flows.

The point of preventing ESD is not to 'float' a circuit and remove it from ground (which doesn't happen when a PC is turned off, it should always be grounded when proper electrical codes are followed), it is to stop the charge from accumulating in the first place.

There are transistors (mosfets) that you can destroy simply by waving your hand over them. most of them are older, and many newer electrical components have ESD protection in their inputs, but that gives you an idea of how easy it is to kill electronic parts with static electric fields.

The way to prevent ESD is to strap in, with a 1MΩ resistor on the strap to prevent electrocution. Other ways are, wear an ESD smock, use an ESD mat and to keep humidity high-ish (like 60%) as water vapor increases charge transport through air.

Another thing to keep in mind is that some materials like plastic and paper and clothing readily create\buildup charge so only use ESD compatible materials near sensitive parts.

Comment: When I first started, ESD was not a concern, and parts were handled rather indiscriminately.  Then when MOSFETs can into widespread use, industry realized how easily they could be damaged by ESD.  But it was deemed too complicated to determine exactly which parts were sensitive and which weren't, so everything was put into ESD bags.  Even hardware (nuts and bolts)!

Comment: now that's nuts

Comment: in the 80's our female lab tech who repaired the Tek Diff Probes rated at 25V was pizzed off at Eng who ignored the rating. You just had to look sideways to generate 25V on 1pF probes.

Comment: In hardware assembly you don't want people tearing open normal plastic bags to get out the screws to fit the PCB into the housing, as there are too many ways sensitive and charged items can come into contact.  So rather than a strict SOP that still relies on everything working properly, it's simpler to remove a source. When we tested wrist straps in use in a previous job we found a wide variation of effective resistances. Skin moisture content is an obvious cause, as is fit (@SteveSh and Tony)

Comment: However a field trick is to power off the system, keeping it grounded, and keep in contact with the chassis.  Ideally you'd rest the forearm of your main working hand on bare metal.

Comment: @Tony & Chris - Well, they've finally gotten away from the hardware-in-the-ESD-bags mentality, thank goodness.  But we still tend to err on the "better be safe than sorry" side of things.

Comment: "which doesn't happen when a PC is turned off, it's always grounded" You're assuming here PCs are always grounded. Which is *usually* true, but I've seen situations (primarily in small companies) where the receptacle wasn't grounded so the PC couldn't have been either. And yes, one of those companies became increasingly concerned about ESD. Interesting place...

Comment: @Mast good point, grounding only works if the codes are followed

Answer (score 4):

No.

Method 1 still relies on person also grounded with static bleeding leakage resistance. (1M)

But generally if person keeps at least one finger on case,  so as at the same potential as board at all times, then there is less risk of generating or discharging a HV charge dump to an ESD sensitive  node. But this can restrict your actions to one hand unless you stretch your fingers and don't forget, this is a *bandaid* solution.

Boards should be handled by the edge or supply rail, ground to neutralize.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter wether or not the device is powered. Any two objects that are not electrically connected with each other don't happen to be on the same potential, which can lead to an electrostatic discharge.
The potential difference (aka voltage) between you and your pc can easily be in the range of several kV, which is out of the specs for most of the components that are involved. From this perspective your pc's 12V don't make much of a difference.

So, no, simply shutting down and unplugging is no esd protection.

Comment: Does it still cause damage if the static is discharging into the PC (plugged in and off) to ground?

Comment: If there is any kind of discharge, then there can be damage. It does not matter at what potential something is, point is in the potential difference between things, and discharge surge current that happens to equalize potentials.

Comment: @Ninja2k What do you mean? The charge is always discharged to ground, the question is, is there any circuit in between.

Answer (score 1):

Standard practice at our place is:

1) Always place equipment on an ESD mat, if practical.

2) Wear ESD lab coats.

3) Wear ESD wrist straps.

If the equipment is too big to fit onto the mat, it or whatever it is attached to must be grounded.  When working on such a configuration the ground clip for the wrist strap is attached to the equipment ground (chassis) before removing or working on any installed components.

Answer (score 0):

It will if the source of the ESD is also grounded...in the case of a human, probably by wearing a ground strap connected to the same ground as the computer.  However, most people don't bother when using a computer, so they're protected pretty well.

If you're talking about servicing a computer, you should do it on a static mat on a bench in a lab with static floor coverings, a wrist strap, and bunny slippers.

If you're a private individual without access to all these toys, get a wrist strap and clip it to the computer chassis for best effect.  You still need to be careful about anything outside the chassis (spare/new parts, etc) but it's better and safer than working on a unit plugged into the wall.

Comment: So if I am connected to the case, but then grab a stick of memory from a separate box that isn't grounded. I can still damaged the memory?

Comment: Yes there can be damage, as the memory stick can be charged to different potential than you and the PC are, and when you touch it, the charges flow redistribute to equalize potentials.

Comment: @Ninja2k if you leave the RAM in its anti-static packaging until ready, then picking up the packaging while connected to the PC case will equalise the potentials without damaging the RAM. You can then handle the RAM and plug it in.